# Can therapeutic training be dangerous?

Tags: health

Kinda depressed and the only thing that gets me through is training.
spend about 5 hours training everyday, because when I don't train, I think...
And when I think shit goes south and I just want to sleep forever.
Stuff is getting worse,thinking about increasing the training sessions to 7 or 8 hours a day. But got a family to feed so getting health problems is no good.
Is it dangerous to train this much? I'm not really sore and I don't think I would even notice if I was.
What's my training like? Literally everything.... Maxes...drop sets, cardio... German volume... Giant sets, isolations, compounds...
I'm not a bodybuilder, I just blast metal in my ears and turn off my brain as I train.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.  You should be asking why you are depressed and seek help for that.  Excessive training will not resolve any underlying issues.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with long training sessions. However, if they are not done carefully, ie being careful with rest times and insuring enough fueling etc, you are at great risk of injury (muscle strains, tears, tendonitis, etc). It seems like you're mostly trying to deal with depression though, which is a bigger issue than tendonitis in my opinion. You should seek help from a GP or mental health professional to figure out some more sustainable coping mechanisms.